# scipy kmeans -- how to get actual threshold between clusters

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means

Using scipy kmeans I can get the centroids of my clusters with

```
centroids, variance = kmeans(pixel,3)
```

and also an array showing which value is assigned to which cluster:

```
code, distance = vq(features, centroids)
```

But how do I get the actual threshold values **separating** the clusters from each other? Is there any variable or command containing these?

thanks for any advice

Answer (score 2):

K-means does not use numerical thresholds.

Every point belongs to the closest cluster, so the "threshold" is the hyperplane (see "[Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram)" in Wikipedia) inbetween of the two nearest cluster centers.

Comment: I just know from satellite image processing programs that these give me a threshold value for the actual image. I guess I need to determine them from the max/min in each cluster then via image statistics.

Comment: Well, the separation is a arbitrarily rotated hyperplane. In RGB space, in 3D. What would a threshold then be?
On the other hand, on 1D data, k-means does not make sense. It's highly inefficient, because 1D can be sorted and then be processed much faster than with "unsorted" k-means.

Comment: I used k-means in a satellite image processing software. There I received the thresholds separating image pixel values into the various clusters. I see it as a  histogram based separation for a single image channel and need the dividing lines in the histogram. K-means seems to be in satellite image analysis a generally used method. Anyway -- it works with scipy python, but I need to extract the values where clusters separate

Comment: Again, how would a threshold in multiple dimensions look like? On grayscale data it's simple, a numerical threshold value such as (x1 + x2)/2